# Start graphical program from TTY

Tags: ssh, xorg

I'm trying to design a digital signage system and I've hit a stumbling block. I've installed Xorg to run the graphical signage app. By default the server shows the X server on the main display (as intended), however I was wondering if it is possible to log in via SSH and then run a command (start-xibo.sh for arguments sake) and have this run the program on the X display?

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want your app to run locally to the box you ssh'ed into?  Or remotely on the box you ssh'ed FROM?

Comment: Similar questions at [unix.se]: [Is there a way to communicate with someone at their desktop?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13085) [ssh DISPLAY variable](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/10121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update the question for clarity, from reading this it sounds like you are trying to run a graphical app and have it appear on the X server running locally on the box you ssh'ed into.  If that is the case you need to set the DISPLAY variable, you can get more information about that here:

http://www.cisl.ucar.edu/docs/ssh/guide/node29.html

http://support.objectplanet.com/esupport/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=17

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using OpenSSH client, connect like this:

```
ssh user@host -X
```

Then run you X program. It should appear at your local machine.

*P.S. There can be some trouble with Xauthority. I can't remember at the moment but if you get it - leave a comment.*

Comment: The 'xauth' program must be installed on the remote host and ~user/.Xauthority must be writeable by the user.